# Update class object using a function from another class using multiprocessing

Tags: python, performance, multiprocessing

I have a class `Population` that consists of instances of a class `Individual`. One can change a property of the individuals using a function `change_val`; in my actual code this change can take a long time and the processing time can differ a lot between individuals. The change of one individual is independent of other individuals and therefore I would like to use multiprocessing to speed up the process of updating all the individuals (compared to just using a simple for-loop) in a population.

That is the skeleton of my code for a toy system:

```
import numpy as np
import multiprocessing as mp


class Population(object):

    def __init__(self, pool_proc):
        self.individuals = []
        self.pool_proc = pool_proc

    def add_individual(self, individual):
        self.individuals.append(individual)

    def change_individuals_loop(self):
        # in a loop, it works fine
        for indi in self.individuals:
            indi.change_val()

    def change_individuals_multi(self):
        # this does -of course - not work as change_val is not known. How would it be done correctly?
        self.pool_proc.apply_async(change_val, self.individuals)

    def print_pop(self):
        for indi in self.individuals:
            print "value: {}, exponent: {}".format(indi.val, indi.exponent)


class Individual(object):

    def __init__(self, some_val, exponent):
        self.val = some_val
        self.exponent = exponent

    def change_val(self):
        self.val = self.val ** self.exponent


if __name__ == '__main__':

    # just for reproducibility purposes
    np.random.seed(1)

    my_pool = mp.Pool(processes=5)
    my_pop = Population(my_pool)

    for indi in range(1, 6):
        my_pop.add_individual(Individual(indi, np.random.choice(5)))

    print "initially:"
    my_pop.print_pop()
    my_pop.change_individuals_loop()
    print "\nfirst iteration:"
    my_pop.print_pop()
```

My question is how I would have to rewrite the function `change_individuals_multi` so that it gives me the same output as `change_individuals_loop`.

The problem is that the line

```
self.pool_proc.apply_async(change_val, self.individuals)
```

does - of course - not work as the function `change_val` is unknown. How would I have to modify this line or the code structure to make it work? If there is something more appropriate for these purposes than `apply_async`, recommendations in this regard are more than welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make it into a function:

```
self.pool_proc.apply_async(lambda individual: individual.change_val(), self.individuals)
```

To get values back you need to return something, and process the return value. There are many ways to do so, one example:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def workerfn((ndx, individual)):
    individual.change_val()
    return ndx, individual.val

...
pool = Pool(...)
for ndx, val in pool.imap_unordered(workerfn, enumerate(self.individuals)):
    self.individuals[ndx].val = val
```

**Update:** why is multiprosessing slower for 100 000 individuals?

Most people who've tried multi-threading/processing run into this early.  The reason is simple: overhead.  In the single-threaded version you do a function call + exponentiation + assignment, while in the multithreaded version you do everything you do in the single threaded version + start process pool + serialize 100K individuals + deserialize 100K individuals + interprocess communication (individuals) + serialization of 100K results + deserialization of same + interprocess communication (results) + assigning the results to the objects... I'm not surprised that it's slower ;-)

To make multiple processes work faster on a regular multi-core setup (I'm not talking about 100s of cores), you want lots of work/data, divided into larger chunks that you distribute to each process. E.g. divide 100 000/number of cores and send a list of individuals instead of sending them one-by-one.

When you're sending objects to another process, Python needs to serialize and deserialize them since the other process runs a completely separate Python interpreter. This takes loads of time compared to sending basic types like tuples/lists/etc. Try sending the parameters for the computation instead of Individual objects.

Finally, the amount of work to be done needs to take longer than it takes to do the interprocess call+return.

Comment: Thanks. That does not update my individuals, unfortunately, when I run `my_pop.change_individuals_multi()`. Could you try to run it, maybe I miss something...!?

Comment: It updates, but only the copy of Individual that is sent to the subprocess (this isn't shared memory, but copied values).  If you want results back you'll need to create a mechanism for it like map_async + a return value + a for-loop.

Comment: And how would I do this? :)

Comment: That gives me `TypeError: workerfn() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)`. Also, do you still need the first line you posted in your answer?

Comment: Sorry, missing parenthesis in workerfn (you can also upack the parameters inside the function..)

Comment: Thanks! That seems to work now (I moved the for loop into `change_individuals_multi`); upvoted (I wait for a bit longe rand than accept it if nothing better shows up). Why did you choose `imap_unordered`?

Comment: And one more question: Would you always initialize a new `Pool` and close it after each function call or pass it like I did?

Comment: I  had a code sample using imap_unordered, and it's perhaps closest in meaning to map_async.  Initializing the pool once works well, but it takes a while so it can sometimes be better to initialize it when needed.

Comment: I did some timing with 100000 individuals and the for-loop version is far faster than the multiprocessing. Might be because this `change_val` function is far too simple but was still surprising to see.

Comment: I'm not that surprised ;-)   I've updated my answer.